# How to specify a file to run everyday in crontab

Tags: linux, file, cron

I wants to run a file by everyday using crontab. But i have confusion on specifying the file in crontab. So, please suggest me to mention the file to run everyday ( start of the day, for example: 12:00 am ). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "file" you mean an executable shell script, then this will do:

```
00 00 * * * /path/to/the/executable/file.sh
```

It will run at midnight every day. You should enter this line in a file that will open when you invoke `crontab -e` command. Once you edit it, save and quit, and crontab will verify whether syntax you entered is correct, so watch the output in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format:
`0 0 * * * command`

- [check examples here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 # minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week

 * 12 * * * /home/mydirectory/myscript.sh
 * 23 * * * /home/mydirectory/myotherscript.sh
 58 23 * * * /home/mydrectory/two_minutes_to_midnight.sh
 * 0 * * * /home/mydirectory/goodnight.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

to make a crontab work, you can read an official doc, there are many of them, and depends on you operational system. But speaking od rules? i'll give some examples:

Common rules :

```
############################################################################
#
#    * * * * * running command
#    - - - - -
#    | | | | |
#    | | | | ----- day of week (0 - 7) (sunday =0 or =7)
#    | | | ------- month (1 - 12)
#    | | --------- day (1 - 31)
#    | ----------- hour (0 - 23)
#    ------------- minute (0 - 59)
#
###########################################################################
```

So if you  want to call shell script that works with your files every "x" minutes you can make such a rule :

```
# work every two minutes
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/sbin/work_script.sh
```

also, between ranges:

```
# works every 5 minutes between 7 and 22 hours
*/5 7-22 * * * /usr/local/sbin/work.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to intialize the crontab entry to run it everyday.

Syntax : * 10 * * * /home/nagios/myscript.sh

Add the entry #crontab -e and save.
The above command will the command daily at 10 am in the morning.